# Scatter plot different groups by colors, using groups that have NaN

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data frame in pandas:

```
               d1_a    d2_a               d3_a    group

BI59           NaN     0.023333           NaN     2
BI71           NaN     0.173333           NaN     2
BI52           NaN          NaN           NaN     1
BI44      0.450000          NaN           NaN     1
BI36           NaN     0.286667           NaN     2
BI29           NaN     0.030000           NaN     2
BI50           NaN     0.633333           NaN     2
BI63           NaN     0.110000           NaN     2
BI64           NaN     0.320000           NaN     2
BI65      0.206667          NaN           NaN     1
BI67           NaN     0.216667           NaN     2
BI68           NaN     0.473333           NaN     2
BI71           NaN     0.053333           NaN     2
BI72           NaN     0.006667           NaN     2
BI75           NaN     0.430000           NaN     2
BI76           NaN     0.260000           NaN     2
BI78           NaN     0.250000           NaN     2
BI81           NaN     0.006667           NaN     2
BI83           NaN     0.603333           NaN     2
BI84           NaN          NaN      0.196667     3
BI86           NaN          NaN      0.046667     3
BI89           NaN     0.110000           NaN     2
BI91           NaN          NaN      0.213333     3
BI93           NaN     0.443333           NaN     2
BI97      0.586667          NaN           NaN     1
BI98      0.380000          NaN           NaN     1
BI99      0.016667          NaN           NaN     1
BI11           NaN     0.206667           NaN     2
BI12           NaN     0.500000           NaN     2
BI17      0.626667          NaN           NaN     1
```

The `BI##` is the index column, the groups that the rows belong to are denoted by the group column. So d1_a is group 1, d2_a is group 2 and d3_a is group 3. Also, the numbers on the index column would be the x axis.  How do I create a scatter plot, with each group being represented by a different color?  When I try plotting I get empty plots.

If I try something like `subset_d1_a = df['d1_a'].dropna()` and do something similar for each group then I can remove the NaNs but now the arrays are of different lengths and I cannot plot them all on the same graph.

Preferably I'd like to do this in seaborn but any method in python will do.

So far, this is what I'm doing, now sure if I'm going down the right path:

```
subset = pd.concat([df.d1_a, df.d2_a, df.d3_a], axis=1)
subset = subset.sum(axis=1)
subset = pd.concat([subset,df.group], axis=1)
subset = subset.dropna()
g = subset.groupby('groups')
```

Comment: in your desired scatter plot, what will be the values on the x axis? I assume `d1_a`, `d2_a` and `d3_a` will be the values on the y axis. Would it be the `##` in the `BI##` string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what a scatter chart would look like given your data, but you could do something like this:

```
colors = {1: 'red', 2: 'green', 3: 'blue'}
df.iloc[:, :3].sum(axis=1).plot(kind='bar', colors=df.group.map(colors).tolist()
```

[image]

Comment: Is this what you want? If not, please explain what is missing or wrong.

Comment: what would be needed to add a legend, that corresponded to the groups? 

`df.iloc[:, :3].sum(axis=1).plot(kind='bar', colors=df.group.map(colors).tolist(),legend=df.group.map(colors).tolist()) ` ?